# Search filter AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am working on a code where a table data can be searched with a text box entry.

My HTML code goes as follows,

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <div><input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Enter Search Text" /><br><br></div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Salary PA</th>
            <th>Date Of Joining</th>
            <th>Programs Completed</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="person in people|filter:searchText">
            <td>{{person.name|uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{person.salaryPA|currency}}</td>
            <td>{{person.Doj|date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
            <td>{{person.ProgramsCompleted|number}}</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Java Script:

```
angular.module("myModule", []).controller("myController", functionCall);
function functionCall($scope) {
var people = [{
        name: "Hulk",
        salaryPA: 25000,
        Doj: new Date("March 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 250,
    }, {
        name: "Superman",
        salaryPA: 12000,
        Doj: new Date("March 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 200,
    }, {
        name: "Batman",
        salaryPA: 12500,
        Doj: new Date("January 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 180,
    }];
$scope.people = people;
}
```

Output:

[image]

The third row in the table does not have the character 'r'. But when I search with 'r', filter is not working as it should. Could anyone help me figure this?

Thanks

Comment: Even the first row don't have r See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zjwvfuyd/86/ It works as it should be

Comment: Do you want to apply filter for all columns or any specific column?

Comment: @GangadharJannu For all column

Answer (score 1):

For all those who answered, the issue is with angular version. It is working until 1.3 `older version` and not working after that `latest versions`

## Not working

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/cmr9xxsk/) with angular 1.4.0

## Working

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gangadharjannu/exr0dh40/) with angular 1.3.9

*I still needs to figure out what is cauing the issue*

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom filter like following. That will work

```
.filter('SalaryFilter', function() {
  return function(people, searchText) {
    return people.filter(function(person) {
      if (
        person.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
        person.salaryPA === searchText ||
        person.Doj === new Date(searchText) || 
        person.ProgramsCompleted === searchText
      ) {
        return vendor;
      }
    });
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `Doj` which contains `r` in months like March and January. So filter is working properly.

Comment: I thought that too but date filter works only for the first three characters of Month. I have to search Jan for January.

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myModule',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope) {
    var people = [{
        name: "Hulk",
        salaryPA: 25000,
        Doj: new Date("March 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 250,
    }, {
        name: "Superman",
        salaryPA: 12000,
        Doj: new Date("March 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 200,
    }, {
        name: "Batman",
        salaryPA: 12500,
        Doj: new Date("January 18, 2014"),
        ProgramsCompleted: 180,
    }];
$scope.people = people;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myModule">
 <div ng-controller="myController">
 <div><input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Enter Search Text" /><br><br></div>
        <table>
            <thead>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Salary PA</th>
            <th>Date Of Joining</th>
            <th>Programs Completed</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="person in people|filter:searchText">
            <td>{{person.name|uppercase}}</td>
            <td>{{person.salaryPA|currency}}</td>
            <td>{{person.Doj|date:"MM/dd/yyyy"}}</td>
            <td>{{person.ProgramsCompleted|number}}</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using angular CDN ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js. Your version of angular is working file. Could you help me figure out with newer version?

Comment: because value of `Doj` property contains `r` in `March` and `January`. There is no issue with the `code` and angular `version`.